# What is the Purpose of Links table here?

Tags: python, sql, many-to-many

I am doing Course 5 of Python for Everybody specialization.
I got this code as a sample from the instructor.
A couple of things I can't understand is what exactly is the purpose of the Links table here.

```
cur.execute('''CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Pages
    (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY , url TEXT UNIQUE, html TEXT,
     error INTEGER, old_rank REAL, new_rank REAL)''')

cur.execute('''CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Links
    (from_id INTEGER, to_id INTEGER)''')

cur.execute('''CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Webs (url TEXT UNIQUE)''')
```

As I am new to Programming this is the first big Assignment I really need to clear this thing.
[By the way this link to Spider.py](https://www.py4e.com/code3/pagerank/spider.py)
Thanks in advance

Comment: I suggest breaking the code down so that you can isolate and replicate ***only*** the part you don't understand.  Posting that much code to query a single line is a sign that you haven't really understood the rest of the code either; that would be a start.  An example of the philosophy I refer to is here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Ok I got your Point

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Links table is the connection between the pages which are crawled and links the pages which are crawled from the page. Of course, this is not the best approach it can be improved in many ways as you are a beginner I will not go in detail.
Example:
If you just add web https://example.com in the table of the webs this web will also be added in the pages table so assume this is your first website and the links we got from this website are two in number so links table will store this and keep a record of it.
The links table will be something like this.
1 2
1 3.
This is what I got by looking at your code

Comment: Do you know why we were deleting data from the Links table at line 75

Comment: `cur.execute('DELETE from Links WHERE from_id=?', (fromid, ) )`
It is for a double check just to avoid redundancy